# Editable javascript grid system with linked relationships

Tags: javascript, datagrid, matrix

I am trying to find an existing JavaScript library which allows the creation of multiple editable datagrids. In addition, I need to be able to link the cells of the various datagrids such that editing cell (1,1) in grid1 causes updates to the mapped cells in the related grids. I would like to express the relationships between the data in the various grids as formulas such that any updates trigger re-flow the the linked grids.

Are there any existing libraries for accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Handsontable](http://handsontable.com/). The cell mapping would need to be implemented by yourself using the `onChange` callback.